# lightning:recordForm display addresses fields as google maps reference with image

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, google-map

I'm working with lightning:recordForm and when adding an address field it displays like this:

[image]

And that text is a redirection to the google maps page:

[image]

But what I really want is that field to have the text with data and also a little iframe with the map itself like it's disposed in the details page of the record with the standard.

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

Not if you want to stick to using lightning:recordForm, because the 'linkifying' comes standard with Salesforce fields and there is nothing one can do about it. But you have options. Have you looked at [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm)? You could create a new generic component that handles iframe which you can embed within the parent component.

> iFrame.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName">

    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="rootURL" type="String" default="" required="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="frameWidth" type="String" default="100%"/>
    <aura:attribute name="frameHeight" type="String" default="600px"/>
    <aura:attribute name="allowScrolling" type="String" default="yes"/>
    <aura:attribute name="includeIdInURL" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <aura:attribute name="parameter1Name" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter1Value" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter2Name" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter2Value" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter3Name" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter3Value" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter4Name" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter4Value" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter5Name" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="parameter5Value" type="String" default=""/>

    <aura:if isTrue="{!!empty(v.rootURL)}">
        <iframe scrolling="{!v.allowScrolling}" src="{!v.rootURL + '?' + v.parameter1Name + '=' + v.parameter1Value + '&amp;' + v.parameter2Name + '=' + v.parameter2Value + '&amp;' + v.parameter3Name + '=' + v.parameter3Value + '&amp;' + v.parameter4Name + '=' + v.parameter4Value + '&amp;' + v.parameter5Name + '=' + v.parameter5Value + '&amp;output=embed' + if(v.includeIdInURL, '&amp;id=' + v.recordId, '') }" width="{!v.frameWidth}" height="{!v.frameHeight}" style="border:none;"></iframe>
        <aura:set attribute="else">
            No URL specified. 
        </aura:set>
    </aura:if>

</aura:component>
```

And then use it like so in:

> lightning:recordEditForm

```
<aura:component>

        <lightning:recordEditForm
            recordId="a00R0000000jq5eIAA"
            objectApiName="Kal__c">
            <!-- the messages component is for error messages -->
            <lightning:messages />

            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Name" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Address_c" />
            <lightning:inputField fieldName="Phone__c" />
            <c:iFrame rootURL="https://www.google.com"/>
            <div class="slds-m-top_medium">
                <lightning:button disabled="{!v.disabled}" variant="brand" type="submit" name="save" label="Save" />
            </div>
        </lightning:recordEditForm>


</aura:component>
```